# object '.' not found when using paste

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm fairly new to using R, but I'm trying to create a database of tv series from imdb. I've found a video on web scraping with R by dataslice on youtube and have been following his process. However, I'm running into an issue:

When using the paste function I'm getting an object not found error.

Here's my code so far:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/?sort=rk,asc&mode=simple&page=1"
page = read_html(link)

name = page |> html_nodes(".titleColumn a") |> html_text()
movie_links = page |> html_nodes(".titleColumn a") |>
  html_attr("href") |> paste0("https://www.imdb.com", .)
year = page |> html_nodes(".secondaryInfo") |> html_text()
rating = page |> html_nodes("strong") |> html_text()
```

After running the script, I get the following:

> movie_links = page |> html_nodes(".titleColumn a") |>
> html_attr("href") |> paste0("https://www.imdb.com", .)

> Error in paste0(html_attr(html_nodes(page, ".titleColumn a"), "href"),  :
> object '.' not found

Any assistance or further explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We could use a lambda expression

```
movie_links <- page |> html_nodes(".titleColumn a") |>
  html_attr("href") |> {\(x) paste0("https://www.imdb.com", x)}()
```

-output

```
> head(movie_links)
[1] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5491994/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=12230b0e-0e00-43ed-9e59-8d5353703cce&pf_rd_r=YX7K2DGHY47VY76DHMTJ&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=toptv&ref_=chttvtp_tt_1"
[2] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=12230b0e-0e00-43ed-9e59-8d5353703cce&pf_rd_r=YX7K2DGHY47VY76DHMTJ&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=toptv&ref_=chttvtp_tt_2"
[3] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0795176/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=12230b0e-0e00-43ed-9e59-8d5353703cce&pf_rd_r=YX7K2DGHY47VY76DHMTJ&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=toptv&ref_=chttvtp_tt_3"
[4] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185906/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=12230b0e-0e00-43ed-9e59-8d5353703cce&pf_rd_r=YX7K2DGHY47VY76DHMTJ&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=toptv&ref_=chttvtp_tt_4"
[5] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7366338/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=12230b0e-0e00-43ed-9e59-8d5353703cce&pf_rd_r=YX7K2DGHY47VY76DHMTJ&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=toptv&ref_=chttvtp_tt_5"
[6] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306414/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=12230b0e-0e00-43ed-9e59-8d5353703cce&pf_rd_r=YX7K2DGHY47VY76DHMTJ&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=toptv&ref_=chttvtp_tt_6"
```